# Require image in React Native with automatic DPI path append

Tags: image, react-native

If I have this object:

```
const images = {
    foo: require('./images/foo.jpg'),
    bar: require('./images/bar.jpg')
}
```

and then render like so:

```
const activeImage = images[ACTIVE] // could be foo or bar

<Image
    source={activeImage}
/>
```

Will this handle the automatic appending of @2x, @3x? If I remove the ".jpg" from the `require` calls, it complains because it can't find the module.

What's the best approach here?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, metro bundler will automatically resolve the best image for the device, so your approach is correct.

It is all very neatly explained in the official documentation [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#static-image-resources).